# How to get page_id for url rewrite or how to use page slug for calling a page?

Tags: pages, url-rewriting, id

I would like to simply create an url rewrite that takes the third argument and matches it to its corresponding pages, ignoring the other two arguments.

```
domain.com/argument1/argument2/page-slug = 'index.php?page_id=XXX';
```

Is it possible to call a page via it's slug instead of it's ID, or can I somehow generate the id, based on a pages slug?

UPDATE:

I actually got a lot further here now:

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'mmp_rewrite_rules');

function mmp_rewrite_rules($rules) {
   $newRules  = array();
   $newRules['bus-tours/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?bus-tours=$matches[3]';
   $newRules['(.+)/?$']                     = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]';
   //$newRules['bus-tours/(.+)/(.+)/?$']    = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[2]';

return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
}
```

What this allows me is:

```
/bus-tours -> and it shows the bus-tours pages.
/bus-tours/California -> and it shows me the child page of bus-tours, which is Calfironia
/bus-tours/california/SanFran/Tourx -> and it shows me the CPT post for TourX
```

So, pretty good for now. Tho, since I am using a lot of CPT's I would like to modify the first rule so "bus-tours" can be replaced with a variable.

```
$newRules['(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?$matches[1]=$matches[3]';
```

This doesn't work. Any help here?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

Use `pagename` instead of `page_id` to query by slug. Note that if a page is a child of another page, `pagename` has to be the full parent/child path to the page, since slugs only have to be unique per-level in hierarchical post types. See [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for the full list of query vars.

Answer (score 0):

You can try selecting the `$post_id` where `$page_name = $page_name`

Comment: Please expand upon this answer. As is, it is not very useful for anyone who doesn't already know what to do